# not passing rows count of 2d arrays to a function in c

Tags: c, rows, sizeof, multidimensional-array

can i do some calculation using the sizeof operator in c to get
the rows count inside a function who receives as a parameter only
a two dimensional array without any information about rows or columns count in this passed array?

```
void main(void){
    int A[5][6];
    int columnsC = sizeof(A[0]) / sizeof(int);
    int rowsC = ( sizeof(A)/sizeof(int) ) / columnsC;
    printf("rows: %d\ncolumns: %d\n", rowsC, columnsC);

    getch();
}
```

the previous code worked for me, but i can't find a helpful resource to know how to apply this on a function of the following header:

```
void fun(int arr[][10])
```

i"m studying a course on Programming Languages Principles, and some times think of things differently and look for learning resources, and this helps a lot, but not this time apparently.

i admire any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There's no way find the size of an array when passed to a function. Array decays into a pointer when passed to a function.

This:

```
void fun(int arr[][10])
```

is actually syntatic sugar for:

```
void fun(int (*arr)[10])
```

Instead you can pass the size as a thrid argument or size as an element of the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible, unless you either pass a length, or you specifically allocate one extra row to the array. This extra row can contain a null character. In the function fun, then you can use a while loop to cycle through the array until you hit the null value.

```
int i = 0;
while (1) {
    if(arr[i]==NULL){
        //exits when hits end    
        break;
    }
    //do stuff with arr[i]
    i++;
}
```